# How to allocate more memmory to the client on minecraft forge MDK

Tags: java, intellij-idea, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am starting with minecraft modding on forge and when i run client on the gradle tab on Intellij it runs with a memmory heap of 257 megabytes of memory so its very slow how can i increase that number?

Comment: Check the running param such as `-Xmx256MB` and remove them

Comment: But, where the param is set?

Comment: In intellij, before running it you should have a tab for Java parameters. Maybe [this][https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration.html#create-permanent) can help you

Answer (score 1):

I finally fixed it, i forgot to run the genIntellijRuns before the runClient task then i just added the argument -Xmx(quantity of megabytes of RAM allocated)m in the JVM args and reinstalled my JDK of Java 1.8 since mine was 32 bits that only allowed 1.5 gigabytes of memory to be allocated to a 64 bits JDK